# how to remove property with empty array value from object in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
const obj ={Rating:7.5 , Actor:[], Age:undefined}
```

want to remove Actor:[]

```
function clean(obj) {
  for (var propName in obj) {
    if (obj[propName] === undefined || obj[propName] == [] ) {
      delete obj[propName];
    }
  }
  return obj
}
```

this function is only removing undefined values

Answer (score 0):

Two different javascript objects cannot be equal
to each other.

Below is a demo of that:

```js
console.log([] === [])
console.log([] == [])
```

In your specific case you will have to check two things:

1. The value is an array.
2. The array is actually empty.

If both are true, then your expression should evaluate to true.

```js
let arr = [];
let arr2 = [1];

if(Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length === 0){
console.log('isempty');
}

if(Array.isArray(arr2) && arr2.length === 0){
console.log('isempty');
}
```